# Why does Principal Vagina say, "no relation" after introducing himself?

Tags: dialogue, rick-and-morty

In the Rick and Morty series, we see multiple interactions with Morty's school Principal. His name is Principal Vagina. After he introduces himself, he says, "no relation" afterwards. Why? What joke am I missing? I thought he might be referring to the school name but if so, I'm not getting it.

What's the joke here, or what does he mean when he says it?

Comment: He says it once.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The joke is that the Principal is saying his name has "no relation" to the body part. He is constantly attempting to clarify that his last name is "not a joke" and that it's a real, "possibly Scandanavian" last name.

Comment: Ok, so he's trying to say "vagina" is a word in another language that means something else, it's not referring to a body part. I get it then. I was hoping it was something more in-depth.

Comment: It is, actually, a real Russian last name - I had an actual classmate whose last name was Vagin (Вагин in Cyrillic). He had a sister several years younger than him, attending the same school. And in Russian, to put a last name into its feminine form, you add an "a" to the end. Luckily for them, nobody spoke English back there back then. Also, it's pronounced quite different from the English word, and yes, no relation to the body part.

Comment: @Headcrab, now I'm curious. How is it pronounced? Like Virginia?

Comment: @jinkevin for the male form `VUH-gh'een`, for female `VUH-gh'ee-na` (emphasis on the first syllable). The `gh'` is not the soft sound like in "gin", but the hard sound, like in "grass"

Comment: a second level to the joke could be that the body part in question is involved in an activity something known as "relations".

Comment: @jinkevin In case Slav's explanation is not enough, you can go to google translate, choose Russian as the language to translate from, copy-paste вагина there and press the sound button (the word is different, but it's a homophone).

Comment: @Slav, if someone with that last name will emigrate in US, they surely will be renamed to soft `g` sound by immigration clerk. Ellis island created a lot of "new dynasties" by butchering their last [foreign] names.

Comment: @Slav Interesting.. better not emigrate to a German language country then :)

Comment: @smcs now *I* am curious, what's the connotation in German?

Comment: @user28434 I wouldn't blame the US immigration clerk. Even when getting an "International Passport" inside Russia (i.e. a passport for international travel, written in English), the name would be [transliterated according to standards](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/13368/what-is-the-most-common-transliteration-romanization-standard-of-cyrillic), letter by letter, not by phonetics. So poor girl `вагина` would have a Russian issued passport with `Vagina`. I don't think you can request a different spelling. Better get married soon

Comment: @Slav It means the same as in English and is pronounced as in Russian. So if Mrs. Vagina introduces herself in Germany, that really sounds like the body part.

Comment: As @Michael points out, the second part of the joke is that the Principal has no personal relations or interaction with vagina. Because he is a nerdy school principal and therefore does not attract the ladies at the same rate as the rest of us supermodels.
Wow jokes really are less funny when you break them down like this

Comment: @Headcrab Your first comment could have been an answer.

Comment: @NogShine It doesn't answer the question. It's a semi-relevant semi-curious fact that may give some childish giggles, like, "in Soviet Russia Vaginas have vaginas, LOL!"

Answer (score 37):

When people who have the same (or similar) name as someone famous introduce themselves, they will often get questions as to whether they're related. Think if an American was named Richard Clinton, or Travis Trump.

After a while they will anticipate these questions, and as part of their self-introduction just state flat-out that they aren't related to that famous person it sounds like they are related to. Just to avoid having to be asked: "Hi, my name is Richard Clinton. And before you ask, no, I'm not related to Bill." This can be shortened to "No relation."

This is what the principal is doing. Only instead of a famous person, it's a body part.

Comment: A good example of this is in the movie Office Space, where one of the characters is named "Michael Bolton" and he is constantly asked if he is any relation to the pop singer.  I have the same name as an actor who was fairly well known when I was a child and I got much the same treatment.  My preferred response, especially when it was an adult asking the question, was to say that the actor was named after me.

Comment: @krb Would you be willing to tell us your name? If we promise not to ask that question, even as a joke?

Comment: I feel like this just states the obvious and misses the point if the question.

Comment: @Gnemlock Could you expand on that? Maybe, if I knew what you meant, I could make this answer better. Or I could disagree with you and still maintain that I believe that this is an answer to the question. Regardless, I can't decide until I hear you out.

Comment: The question is asking for an explanation of the context in which the phrase is said, not an explanation of what the phrase means in general. I don't think you can add much more than what has already been said in other answers.

Answer (score 9):

I always understood it as a reference to "not being a pussy".
Thus he is saying his name is not a reference to his character.

Comment: You have more than 50 rep, so you_can_ comment, actually.

Comment: @F1Krazy In what way is this not an answer to the question?

Comment: I couldn't comment before paying this answer... And i think it's just an extension to the first answer.

Comment: Well that definitely adds another layer...

Answer (score 3):

It could also be a nod to Die Hard's [Agent Johnson and Special Agent Johnson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HY_nkgJG3oE).

> AJ: I'm Agent Johnson
>   AJ: And this is Special Agent Johnson
>   AJ: ... No relation

The joke *there* is they have the same surname but they're clearly of different ethnicity.

But in relation to Rick and Morty, Johnson is American slang for penis.

Comment: Seems like a very long stretch without anything to back you up...

Comment: @Gnemlock Oof. It's a sad day when Die Hard isn't considered popular enough to be referenced by a show that [references 80s and 90s pop culture all the time](https://time.com/4868184/rick-morty-easter-eggs/).

Answer (score 1):

To me, having grown up with a TV in the 90's (for good reason: moved to USA for learning the language and culture), this phrase was an instant reference to Tiny Toon Adventures cartoon series, where two major characters - Buster and Babs Bunny (sometimes with Bugs Bunny in the loop) - always introduced themselves with a "No relation!" disclaimer.